# Summarising Data Issue in R

Tags: r, summary

I need to summarise my data for an assignment and I can't understand how I'm not getting it.
I'm a massive newbie re R Studios and going off of the advice Uni has given me (which is abysmal) I've gotten as far as I can.

The main issue is:
"Summarise the number of in-patient admissions within the past year for patients that are
divorced or legally separated."

So far, this is where I'm at:

```
r <- c("Single"= 1, "Other"= 2, "Divorced"= 3, "Married"= 4 )
Group123 <- VisED[(VisED$disposition = 1) & (VisED$maritalstatus)]
```

Admission is 1, Discharged is 0. The vector was to sort out all the different relationship status'.
I thought maybe I had to create a vector of sorts and go from there?

The goal is to get all the admitted patients who are divorced assigned to one variable to then go on and calculate the mean and SD.

I've also tried maritalstatus=divorced but that doesn't work.

```
Group123 <- VisED[(VisED$disposition = 1) & (VisED$maritalstatus=divorced)]
```

And I get

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(VisED, (VisED$disposition = 1) & (VisED$maritalstatus = divorced)) :
```

object 'divorced' not found

Overall though, I am majorly stumped so any advice or anything else I can provide to make this a little easier to understand then let me know.

Thanks! :))

EDIT: Having tried some of comments I'm now receiving this message

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(VisED, (VisED$disposition = 1) & (VisED$maritalstatus ==  :
```

undefined columns selected

In response to this line of code:

```
Group123 <- VisED[(VisED$disposition = 1) & (VisED$maritalstatus == "divorced")]
```

Where have I gone wrong now?

PS. Sorry again

Comment: you'll want to use == instead of = for checking equality. Also don't forget to use ' when dealing with string value. For exampleVisED$maritalstatus == "divorced"

Comment: That's worked a treat, thank you so much! Now though, when I try and find the mean I just keep getting "argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA". Do you have any idea why this could be? Sorry, I know this must be tedious but I'm very unsure. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Two things, you're going to want to put a `,` after the logical statements to let them know you're selecting rows, not columns -- if you leave it out, it assumes you're selecting columns, hence the undefined columns error. Second, to select the column, you need to do `Group123$variable_name`. Replace `nadmissions` below with your variable name. If you simply do `mean(Group123)`, you get that error because you're trying to take the mean of a data frame, not allowed.

```
VisED=data.frame(nadmissions=1:10, disposition=rep(c(1, 0), each=5), maritalstatus=rep(c("divorced"), 10), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
Group123 <- VisED[(VisED$disposition == 1) & (VisED$maritalstatus=="divorced"),]
variable=as.numeric(Group123$nadmissions)
mean(variable, na.rm=TRUE)
3

sd(variable, na.rm=TRUE)
1.581139
```

Comment: Hey! That's great thank you! If possible could you may explain what's happening in each part of the code so I can understand a little better? Thank you again! :)

Comment: The first part is just making a fake data frame analogous to yours, since it wasn’t provided. Again, you need a comma after the == statements to show that you are selecting rows. as.numeric turns characters into numbers in case the column is characters (but isn’t necessary if they are numeric). Try leaving it out and see if you don’t get an error. na.rm means to ignore NA’s (missing values) in your vector. If there are no NAs, it is the same as not saying na.rm=TRUE. Try leaving it out to see if it still works.